# Is there anyway for me to create a Drupal view from sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

Is there anyway for me to create a Drupal view from two MySQL queries.I want to create a view of events one MySQL query is used to bring events that have started and have not finish and the other query is to bring up events that have not started yet and to show a total of 3 items collectively.

Here is the two SQL queries I want to create a view from:

```
    SELECT f.delta      AS field_data_field_session_start_date_delta
     , f.entity_id  AS date_id_date_filter
     , f.delta      AS date_delta_date_filter
     , n.title      AS node_title
     , n.nid        AS nid
     , n.language   AS node_language
     , f.field_session_start_date_value AS field_data_field_session_start_date_field_session_start_date
     , f.field_session_start_date_value2 AS field_data_field_session_start_date_field_session_start_date2
     , 'node'       AS field_data_field_session_start_date_node_entity_type
  FROM `node` n
  JOIN `field_data_field_session_start_date` f
    ON f.entity_id = n.nid
   AND f.entity_type = 'node'
   AND f.deleted = '0'
   AND f.field_session_start_date_value >= NOW()
WHERE n.status = '1'
ORDER
    BY f.field_session_start_date_value ASC
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0


SELECT f.delta      AS field_data_field_session_start_date_delta
     , f.entity_id  AS date_id_date_filter
     , f.delta      AS date_delta_date_filter
     , n.title      AS node_title
     , n.nid        AS nid
     , n.language   AS node_language
     , f.field_session_start_date_value AS field_data_field_session_start_date_field_session_start_date
     , f.field_session_start_date_value2 AS field_data_field_session_start_date_field_session_start_date2
     , 'node'       AS field_data_field_session_start_date_node_entity_type
  FROM `node` n
  JOIN `field_data_field_session_start_date` f
    ON f.entity_id = n.nid
   AND f.entity_type = 'node'
   AND f.deleted = '0'
   AND f.field_session_start_date_value <= NOW()
   AND f.field_session_start_date_value2 > NOW()
WHERE n.status = '1'
ORDER
    BY f.field_session_start_date_value ASC
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know how to create Drupal view from the raw sql - i.e., just one of those queries.

You can use the UNION command to create 1 query that returns the result of both queries (In your case, wrap both queries in parentheses to make sure the ORDER BY and LIMIT are associated with the inner queries):

```
(SELECT f.delta      AS field_data_field_session_start_date_delta
     , f.entity_id  AS date_id_date_filter
     , f.delta      AS date_delta_date_filter
     , n.title      AS node_title
     , n.nid        AS nid
     , n.language   AS node_language
     , f.field_session_start_date_value AS field_data_field_session_start_date_field_session_start_date
     , f.field_session_start_date_value2 AS field_data_field_session_start_date_field_session_start_date2
     , 'node'       AS field_data_field_session_start_date_node_entity_type
  FROM `node` n
  JOIN `field_data_field_session_start_date` f
    ON f.entity_id = n.nid
   AND f.entity_type = 'node'
   AND f.deleted = '0'
   AND f.field_session_start_date_value >= NOW()
WHERE n.status = '1'
ORDER
    BY f.field_session_start_date_value ASC
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0)
UNION
(SELECT f.delta      AS field_data_field_session_start_date_delta
     , f.entity_id  AS date_id_date_filter
     , f.delta      AS date_delta_date_filter
     , n.title      AS node_title
     , n.nid        AS nid
     , n.language   AS node_language
     , f.field_session_start_date_value AS field_data_field_session_start_date_field_session_start_date
     , f.field_session_start_date_value2 AS field_data_field_session_start_date_field_session_start_date2
     , 'node'       AS field_data_field_session_start_date_node_entity_type
  FROM `node` n
  JOIN `field_data_field_session_start_date` f
    ON f.entity_id = n.nid
   AND f.entity_type = 'node'
   AND f.deleted = '0'
   AND f.field_session_start_date_value <= NOW()
   AND f.field_session_start_date_value2 > NOW()
WHERE n.status = '1'
ORDER
    BY f.field_session_start_date_value ASC
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0)
```